# Numpy - automatic implicit conversion of np.arrays into lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, implicit-conversion

I am trying to make a `numpy.array` of other `numpy.array's`, for a Monte Carlo simulation. I would like to take an element of the array (another 1d array) and perform some function on it which returns a subsection of that array, and re-assign it. **Originally all arrays are the same length** which seems to cause the problem.

**I want to do**: e.g.

```
c1 = np.array([np.array(xi) for xi in [[1,2],[1],[1,3]]])
c1[2] = np.array([5])
```

which works fine giving:

```
array([array([1, 2]), array([1]), array([5])], dtype=object)
```

and I get the same sort of structure when I do a transform which leaves all the sub-arrays the same length.

```
c2 = np.array([np.array(xi) for xi in [[1,2],[1],[1,3]]])
c2[1] = np.array([4,5])
```

giving

```
array([array([1, 2]), array([4, 5]), array([1, 3])], dtype=object).
```

**Instead what happens is**: e.g.

When I start all the arrays being the same length they are converted from `np.arrays` into `lists`.

```
c3 = np.array([np.array(xi) for xi in [[1,2],[1,2],[1,4]]])
```

which gives

```
array([[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 4]]).
```

Now if I try to adjust the length of one of the lists

```
c3[1] = np.array([5])
```

I get broadcasting

```
array([[1, 2], [5, 5], [1, 4]])
```

*when instead I wanted*

```
array([array([1, 2]), array([5]), array([1, 4])])
```

**Performance Issues**:

This is all for a Monte Carlo simulation, and typically I am looking to handle an array of about 10'000 sub-arrays, where each sub-array is an array of around 1'000 elements (floats). I have been using numpy because its random number generation is very quick, and it has great performance for vectorised functions, where specifically I want to perform some sort of cumulative sum on these eventually (`np.cumsum`), and some other more esoteric functions. I was able to do this sort of thing with lists, but it took around 20 times longer, and am looking to optimise whenever possible.

Many Thank.

Comment: Have you tested the performance of a list of np.array, instead of np.array of np.array?

Comment: I'd recommend to rethink the approach. Arrays of arrays of varying lengths seem weird, inconvenient and likely slow.

Comment: @kennytm I haven't tested the performance of that because I am making use of `np.insert` via the following: `np.insert(np.array([many_np_arrays]), 0, x0, axis=1).cumsum(axis=1))` where `x0` is a set of initial conditions, and then I turn these into cumulative sums using `.cumsum`. It is very useful having this `np.insert` to add an initial condition, rather than making a `for loop` and then doing some sort of `x0.append(etc)`. Essentially I want to keep also the functionality of `np.array`s. I hope that's clear.

Comment: @ev-br I am considering using a `pandas dataframe` and then doing row and column operations, but am worried about performance speed, as to impose the boundary conditions I want I would need to do many row wise searching algorithms, which I am worried might not be well vectorised, and when I perform these rows I don't know what type of object they will be treated as (`list`, `np.array`, `pd.series`, etc?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numpy does not allow you to change shapes of np.arrays of np.arrays:

```
>>> c3 = np.array([np.array(xi) for xi in [[1,2],[1,2],[1,4]]])
>>> c4 = np.array([c3[:1],np.array([5]), c3[2:]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (1)
```

What you can do is use `dtype=np.ndarry` for `np.empty`:

```
>>> ourList =  [[1,2],[1,2],[1,4]]
>>> c3 = np.empty(len(ourList), dtype=np.ndarray)
>>> for i in xrange(len(ourList)):
>>>     c3[i] = np.array(outList[i])
>>> c3
array([array([1, 2]), array([1, 2]), array([1, 4])], dtype=object)
>>> c3[1] = np.array([5])
>>> c3
array([array([1, 2]), array([5]), array([1, 4])], dtype=object)
```

Is this what you are looking for?

You may want to just put a zero or some huge negative/positive number that won't effect your simulation:

```
>>> c3 = np.array([np.array(xi) for xi in [[1,2],[1,2],[1,4]]])
>>> c3[1] = np.array([5])
>>> c3
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 5],
       [1, 4]])
>>> c3[1][1] = -9999999
>>> c3
array([[       1,        2],
       [       5, -9999999],
       [       1,        4]])
```

Comment: Notice it turns `dtype=np.array` into `dtype=object`.  That kind of array contains pointers to any kind of object;

Comment: That solution works just as I wanted it to! I does mean I have to do a few more lines of code and a few extra concatenated/nested operations (only a few!) than what I had initially envisaged, but now I am reading a performance increases of a factor of 40 above the very initial `list` of `lists` approach, where as my initial `np.array` of `lists` approach (outlines above in the question) only gave a factor of 20 improvement (I say only...). Thanks @Kenneth

Comment: Try `c3[...] = ourList` to fill in the object array.